# How to prove this? "For all sets $A,B\subseteq D$ and functions $f:D\mapsto R$, we have $f(A\cap B)\subseteq(f(A)\cap f(B))$."

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Here's my attempt:

- $f(A∩B) = f(\{x|x∈A∧x∈B\}) = \{f(x)|x∈\{x|x∈A∧x∈B\}\}$
- $f(A)∩f(B) = f(\{x|x∈A\}) ∩ f(\{x|x∈B\}) = \{f(x)|x∈\{x|x∈A\}\} ∩ \{f(x)|x∈\{x|x∈B\}\} = \{x|x∈\{f(x)|x∈\{x|x∈A\}\}∧x∈\{f(x)|x∈\{x|x∈B\}\}\}$

And now I'm stuck. Please help.

Comment: In [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages) you can find links to several posts about this fact: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228613/is-this-a-valid-proof
or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225333/is-this-proof-correct-to-prove-fa-cap-fb-subseteq-fa-cap-b-for-all-fun
or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231145/prove-fs-cap-t-subseteq-fs-cap-ft
or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170725/
or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239783/
or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144870/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$
A\cap B\subset A\implies f(A\cap B)\subset f(A),\\
A\cap B\subset B\implies f(A\cap B)\subset f(B)
$$
so it follows that $f(A\cap B)\subset f(A)\cap f(B)$.

Comment: This is great. But can you explain or prove why if $X \subset Y$, then $f(X) \subset f(Y)$?

Comment: If $y\in f(X)$ then by definition $y=f(s)$ for $s\in X$, but $X\subset Y$, so $s\in Y$ as well, which, together with $y=f(s)$, implies that $y\in f(Y)$.